# How get nonce of smart contract account with JSON RPC function? eth_getTransactionCount only for EXTERNAL accounts right?

Tags: nonce, message

How get nonce of smart contract account with JSON RPC function? (Number of new smart contract accounts created by a smart contract account?)

eth_getTransactionCount only for EXTERNAL accounts so won't work right?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you believe `eth_getTransactionCount` is only for externally owned accounts? In general, Ethereum differentiates very little between accounts with associated code (smart contracts) and externally owned accounts (EOA).

I believe `eth_getTransactionCount` will get you the correct nonce for any account. Note that smart contracts start with a nonce of 1 ([read this](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/09/how-smart-contract-deployment-works/) for some nuance), so that's what you'll see for newly deployed contracts. So you may want to subtract 1 if you're actually wondering how many smart contracts a given contract has created.

Comment: I'm getting bogged down in the wording.....When a smart contract requests something from another smart contract, isn't that called a *message*?  Transactions need digital signatures which smart contract messages do not have right?

Comment: That's correct. `eth_getTransactionCount` should probably be renamed `eth_getNonce`. :-)

Comment: Wow that link you posted is really quite good. ;)  And I see that another word for messages is "internal transactions" which makes everything clear now.  Thanks for the help and the link!

Comment: The fact that nonce values for smart contracts accounts now start at 1 seems to imply the definition of nonces should be changed in the yellow paper now.  They no longer always equal the number of previous transactions sent.